# How to change color in lstlisting (LaTeX) if the first symbol is $?

Tags: latex, listings, lstlisting

By formatting command-line snippets with LaTeX lstlisting, I want to separate input commands from their outputs as follows:

In the command-line snippet:

```
$date
Sat Jun  1 14:31:01 CEST 2019
```

`$date` has to be in blue

`Sat Jun  1 14:31:01 CEST 2019` has to be in black

So the idea is to find all strings with the `$` first symbol and colorize them.

I've search through usual commands as `string` or `comment` with rudimentary regexp but without luck. Is it really possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up `$` as comment character:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
commentstyle=\color{blue},
morecomment=[l]{$},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
$date
Sat Jun  1 14:31:01 CEST 2019
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]